# How to save ip address to a DB from authenticated user with Spring security?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, ip

I need to keep track of the ip address when users log in my spring application.

security.xml:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
    <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
        <salt-source user-property='username' />
    </password-encoder>
</authentication-provider>
```

with bean:

```
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="512" />
</beans:bean>
```

I've a custom userService with a method loadUserByUsername() returning a custom UserDetails. This method get the UserDetails from a database, via a DAO. The UserDetails contains stuffs related to the user such as his username, password, authorities, email address, but also application-specific variables. I need to access these variables in my JSP pages.

I want to save into a database (via a call to a method in a custom service, which call a DAO method) the ip address, timestamp and user id when a user is authenticated successfully in my application.

I'm not sure what to do: should I implement a custom authentication provider? extends DaoAuthenticationProvider? or AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider? or something else?

More general questions:

A. Where can I add a method to call once a user provides the right credentials?

B. How can I retrieve the ip address of the user? (knowing that tomcat runs behind apache in a reverse-proxy).

I tried to look at related questions/answers, but it just made me more confused. If someone could provide a very simple step-by-step implementation, it would be awesome. thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can provide a custom authentication success handler that will be responsible for saving an IP of current user in DB. See **authentication-success-handler-ref** attribute of [**form-login**](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-form-login) tag. It will be good idea to extend one of existing implementations (for example SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler) and add your functionality.

You can get IP after authentication from everywhere just by doing:

```
WebAuthenticationDetails details = (WebAuthenticationDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
String ip = details.getRemoteAddress();
```

Try it. If it gives you wrong IP address due to reverse proxy then consider adding client IP as request header.

Comment: Thank you! It's indeed what I need. I extended SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler and added my code to save the ip address accordingly. However, I'm running tomcat with apache as a reverse proxy. Hence I see only local ip address (127.0.0.1). How do you specify to add the right ip address as a request header in apache? and how do you get that ip address in the authenticationSuccessHandler? thanks!

Comment: Try `String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")`. If client IP is not send by Apache then look into [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_remoteip.html) plugin.